# ERROR: Object is possibly 'null' in angular project for view PDF

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

ERROR IS:

```
printContents = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML.toString();
```

IN LINE 4:

```
print(): void {
    let printContents!: string;
    let popupWin!: any;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML.toString();
    printContents = ((printContents as string) + '').replace('col-sm', 'col-xs');
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`<html lang="fa"><body onload="window.print();">${printContents}</body></html>`);
    popupWin.document.close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` can return undefined if the element does not exist.

`document.getElementById('print')!.innerHTML.toString();` should do the trick.

Comment: I did this but the "document" still has an error:
TSLint: Forbidden non null assertion (no-non-null-assertion)